# If an Eidolon uses Divine Dread and then goes into its sacred statue, does the frightened condition transfer?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, fear

If an Eidolon use Divine Dread and then goes into its sacred statue, does the frightened condition transfer? Or would a PC only be frightened by the eidolon? What if the sacred statue looks exactly like the eidolon?

RAW, I can't find any evidence, but I'm still wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, the frighten effect from Divine Dread requires sight of the Eidolon.

Definitely feels ambiguous, but the wording makes it slightly clearer.

From [Divine Dread](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/eidolon)

> Each creature within 60 feet of the eidolon that can see it must succeed on a DC 15 Wisdom saving throw or be frightened of it for 1 minute...

From [Sacred Animation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/eidolon)

> When the eidolon moves into a space occupied by a sacred statue, the eidolon can **disappear**...

Furthermore, Sacred Animation also states

> The eidolon uses the [sacred statue’s](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sacred-statue) statistics in place of its own.

The [Sacred Statue's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sacred-statue) stat block has:

> **False Appearance.** While the statue remains motionless, it is indistinguishable from a normal statue.

So, if the Eidolon disappears, it's reasonable to say that the targets of Divine Dread cannot see it, as it just looks like the Sacred Statue, which in turn just looks like a normal statue (if it remains motionless).

### If the Statue looks like the Eidolon.

At this stage, I'm not sure.  I think there's cases for and against this.  DM discretion is probably appropriate.